# Maintain transaction for huge amount of insert and update in multiple tables

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

We have to `update`  a **huge amount of data (10 million)** in multiple tables at a time and I want to maintain the data. It means if any error/exception comes during the update or insert statement then it should rollback all the data. I do not want to use `Transaction` and `Rollback` because it will impact the performance. We are planning to execute a stored procedure .

Is there any other way except `Transaction` and `Rollback`.

I am using `SqlServer 2016`.

Comment: thank you for sharing your plans, but what is the question?